# mysql_fetch_assoc with left join causes null id to be returned

Tags: mysql, sql, null, left-join

With mysql_fetch_assoc I am normally able to return all my columns without needing to specify them individually, which is great. The issue occurs where there is no actual row to join to from t2.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

In this case 'id' would come back as NULL from t2 and 12345 from t1. But unfortunately t2 seems to take priority here (probably becomes it comes last in the query) so I end up with $row[id'] being NULL when in reality I hoped for 12345 in my result array with just the other values from t2 being NULL.

Any ideas or workaround for this?

Comment: If 2 tables have same column name like id in your both tables then you have to give them unique aliases because in php key for array or object is unique like you can't have 2 keys with same name and with different values,if you try to do this type of thing it will override the previous value stored at that key

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As requested in comment i am posting it as an answer*

> If 2 tables have same column name like id in your both tables then you
>   have to give them unique aliases because in php key for array or
>   object is unique like you can't have 2 keys with same name and with
>   different values,if you try to do this type of thing it will override
>   the previous value stored at that key

Answer (score 0):

Better to give alias name, but this workaround might solve your problem

```
select t1.*, t2.* LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense??

Comment: @trapper, here we are explicitly asking for t1 columns followed by t2 so that you get Ids in correct order